# Angular: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display extracted data from an API. I am doing so successfully as it is visible in the console.
I run into an error tho when I try to put the data into an array.

Interfaces:

```
interface ISearchResponse {
  appendix: IAppendix;
}

interface IAppendix {
  Airports:IAirport[];
}

interface IAirport {
  name: string;
  city:string;
}
```

The code where the problem is:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('SC: in OnInIt');
    this._searchEngine.getSites().subscribe(sites => {
      this.airports = sites;
      console.log("SC: SITES:"+this.airports.appendix.Airports[0].name);

    },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

The Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: Please include your classes that implement your interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. What I was doing wrong was I gave 'Airports' a capital 'A'. When the JSON data had it as 'airports'. Therefore nothing was going into the array as it did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes **`this.airports.appendix.Airports`** could be empty, Add a check
before accessing elements using index

```
this.airports = sites;
if(this.airports.appendix.Airports && this.airports.appendix.Airports.length > 0 ){
  console.log("SC: SITES:"+this.airports.appendix.Airports[0].name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Unfortunately that throws the same error.

Comment: how do I ensure data is going into the array?

Comment: Its ok, What I was doing wrong was I gave 'Airports' a capital 'A'. When the json had it as 'airports'. Therefore nothing was going into the array.